# Firebase real-time database posting over old images with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to make a simple web page just to play around with Firebase. I'm currently working on users uploading their photos and storing them as well as a reference to them in the database. I had a working version except the only issue was that if multiple users opened the page at the same time, only the most recent post would last. I wanted to use the realtime function to overcome this and have come up with this.

```
var postRef = firebase.database().ref('variables/postNumber');
postRef.on('value',function(snapshot) {
    var postName = snapshot.val();
    var uploader = document.getElementById('uploader');
    var filebutton = document.getElementById('filebutton');

    // get file

    filebutton.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
        var file = e.target.files[0];
        var ext = file.name.split('.').pop();;
        console.log(postName);
        console.log(ext);
        //create a storage ref
        var storageRef = firebase.storage().ref('posts/' + postName + "." + ext);

        var task = storageRef.put(file);
        publishPost(postName, ext);
        function publishPost(postName, ext) {
            firebase.database().ref('posts/' + postName).set({
                postID: postName,
                postDate: Date(),
                fileType : ext
            });
            firebase.database().ref('variables/').set({
                postNumber: postName + 1
            });
        }
        task.on('state_changed',

            function progress(snapshot){
                var percentage = (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) *100;
                uploader.value = percentage;
            },
            function error(err){

            },
            function complete(postName, ext){
                uploader.value = 0;
                window.alert('Your meme Uploaded correctly');

            },
        );
    });
});
```

This works well, always updating the postName variable except when a new user posts, it will rewrite every post to the new post. For example, if user A posts a picture while user B was already on the page, then when user B posts, his post will upload twice the first time overriding user A's post. Can anyone shed some light on why this is happening? I was thinking of moving the listener to start the function but not sure if thats the right choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens is that the event listener is attached to the button every time new value is detected. Which means that the `change` event listener on `filebutton` cannot be in the observer at all.

Working code:

```
let postName = null;

var postRef = firebase.database().ref('variables/postNumber');

postRef.on('value', function(snapshot) {
  const value = snapshot.val();

  if (value === null) {
    // Handle error when no value was returned
    return;
  }

  postName = value;

});

var uploader = document.getElementById('uploader');
var filebutton = document.getElementById('filebutton');

filebutton.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
  if (postName === null) {
    // Handle the case then post name is still null (either wan't loaded yet or couldn't be loaded)
    return;
  }

  var file = e.target.files[0];
  var ext = file.name.split('.').pop();;

  //create a storage ref
  var storageRef = firebase.storage().ref('posts/' + postName + "." + ext);

  var task = storageRef.put(file);
  publishPost(postName, ext);
  function publishPost(postName, ext) {
    firebase.database().ref('posts/' + postName).set({
      postID: postName,
      postDate: Date(),
      fileType : ext
    });
    firebase.database().ref('variables/').set({
      postNumber: postName + 1
    });
  }
  task.on('state_changed', 
  function progress(snapshot){
    var percentage = (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) *100;
    uploader.value = percentage;
  },
  function error(err){

  },
  function complete(postName, ext){
    uploader.value = 0;
    window.alert('Your meme Uploaded correctly');
  });
});
```